# How can I reorder admin bar items?

Tags: admin-menu

I have a plugin that adds custom admin bar items, but I'd like them to appear all the way to the left. I know I can add and remove menu items with `$wp_admin_bar->add_menu()` etc, but how can I reorder them?

Edit: It looks like the admin bar menu item orders are defined in [wp-includes/class-wp-admin-bar.php](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/class-wp-admin-bar.php), but I can't figure out how to change this order from within my plugin function.

```
            add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'wp_admin_bar_sidebar_toggle', 0 );
            add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'wp_admin_bar_wp_menu', 10 );
            add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'wp_admin_bar_my_sites_menu', 20 );
            add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'wp_admin_bar_site_menu', 30 );
```

Answer (score 4):

This is an old question, but for others in the future the answer is.

You can add the following code to `functions.php`.

```
function reorder_admin_bar() {
    global $wp_admin_bar;

    // The desired order of identifiers (items)
    $IDs_sequence = array(
        'wp-logo',
        'site-name',
        'new-content',
        'edit'
    );

    // Get an array of all the toolbar items on the current
    // page
    $nodes = $wp_admin_bar->get_nodes();

    // Perform recognized identifiers
    foreach ( $IDs_sequence as $id ) {
        if ( ! isset($nodes[$id]) ) continue;

        // This will cause the identifier to act as the last
        // menu item
        $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu($id);
        $wp_admin_bar->add_node($nodes[$id]);

        // Remove the identifier from the list of nodes
        unset($nodes[$id]);
    }

    // Unknown identifiers will be moved to appear after known
    // identifiers
    foreach ( $nodes as $id => &$obj ) {
        // There is no need to organize unknown children
        // identifiers (sub items)
        if ( ! empty($obj->parent) ) continue;

        // This will cause the identifier to act as the last
        // menu item
        $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu($id);
        $wp_admin_bar->add_node($obj);
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_before_admin_bar_render', 'reorder_admin_bar');
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Admin_Bar

Answer (score -2):

```
function custom_menu_order($menu_ord) {  
    if (!$menu_ord) return true;  

    return array(  
        'index.php', // Dashboard  
        'separator1', // First separator  
        'edit.php', // Posts  
        'upload.php', // Media  
        'link-manager.php', // Links  
        'edit.php?post_type=page', // Pages  
        'edit-comments.php', // Comments  
        'separator2', // Second separator  
        'themes.php', // Appearance  
        'plugins.php', // Plugins  
        'users.php', // Users  
        'tools.php', // Tools  
        'options-general.php', // Settings  
        'separator-last', // Last separator  
    );  
}  
add_filter('custom_menu_order', 'custom_menu_order'); // Activate custom_menu_order  
add_filter('menu_order', 'custom_menu_order');
```

Comment: It would add value to the solution if you present it with some explanations.

Comment: I tried echoing `$menu_ord`, but it doesn't return anything, so it might be empty. Also, my admin bar items are links with IDs, created with `$wp_admin_bar->add_menu()`, so I'm not sure I can reference them with a `.php` entry.

Comment: Does it work for any items starting with admin.php like `admin.php?page=custom_settings_page`?

Comment: Not helpful.  This answer is about the admin menu.  The question is about the _Admin Bar_.  Different things.